# WordPress Plugin development: Category filter in media library makes the page to reload

Tags: wordpress

I am building a plugin where I have a dropdown category filter on media library.

The filter works fine on list view but on grid view mode when I select a category, rather than media files getting filtered the page refreshes and nothing is filtering.

I am not using any custom taxonomy, so I have register the taxonomy (in my case it is `category` to `attachment` post type)

```
function register_taxonomy_for_post_type() {
    //$this->taxonomy = apply_filters(  'cool_media_taxonomy', $this->taxonomy );

    if( taxonomy_exists( $this->taxonomy ) ) {
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $this->taxonomy, $this->post_type );
    } else {
        $args = array(
            'hierarchical'  => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'update_count_callback' => array( $this, 'update_count' ),
        );

        register_taxonomy( $this->taxonomy, array( $this->post_type ), $args );
    }
}

add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_taxonomy_for_post_type' ), 0 );
```

**Localization:**

```
function enqueue_media_action() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'classes/class-walker-category-mediagrid-filter.php';

    global $pagenow;

    if( wp_script_is( 'media-editor' ) && 'upload.php' === $pagenow ) {
        if( $this->taxonomy !== 'category' ) {
            $options = array(
                'taxonomy'      => $this->taxonomy,
                'hierarchical'  => true,
                'hide_empty'    => false,
                'show_count'    => true,
                'orderby'       => 'name',
                'order'         => 'ASC',
                'value'         => 'id',
                'echo'          => false,
                'walker'        => new WalkerCategoryMediaGridFilter(),

            );
        } else {
            $options = array(
                'taxonomy'      => $this->taxonomy,
                'hierarchical'  => true,
                'hide_empty'    => false,
                'show_count'    => true,
                'orderby'       => 'name',
                'order'         => 'ASC',
                'value'         => 'id',
                'echo'          => false,
                'walker'        => new WalkerCategoryMediaGridFilter(),
            );
        }

        $attachment_terms = wp_dropdown_categories( $options );
        $attachment_terms = preg_replace( array( "/<select([^>]*)>/", "/<\/select>/" ), "", $attachment_terms );

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo '/* <![CDATA[ */';
        echo 'var coolmediafilter_taxonomies = {"' . $this->taxonomy . '":{"list_title":"' . html_entity_decode( __( 'All categories', $this->text_domain ), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) . '","term_list":[' . substr( $attachment_terms, 2 ) . ']}};';
        echo '/* ]]> */';
        echo '</script>';

        wp_enqueue_script('coolmediafilter-media-views', plugins_url( 'js/cmf-media-views.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'media-views' ), '1.0.0', true );

        $cats = $this->get_accessible_categories();

        $filtered_cats = array(
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'include'    => $cats,
            'orderby'    => 'name',
            'order'      => 'ASC',
        );

        wp_localize_script( 'coolmediafilter-media-views', 'MediaLibraryCategoryFilterOptions',
            array(
                'terms'     => get_terms(
                    $this->taxonomy,
                    $filtered_cats
                ),
            )
        );
    }

    wp_enqueue_style( 'coolmediafilter', plugins_url( 'css/coolmediafilter.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0.0' );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_media_action' ) );
```

**The script:**

```
(function(){
    /**
     * Create a new MediaLibraryTaxonomyFilter we later will instantiate
     */
    var MediaLibraryCategoryFilter = wp.media.view.AttachmentFilters.extend({
        id: 'media-view-category-filter',

        createFilters: function() {
            var filters = {};
            // Formats the 'terms' we've included via wp_localize_script()
            _.each( MediaLibraryCategoryFilterOptions.terms || {}, function( value, index ) {
                filters[ value.term_id ] = {
                    text: value.name,
                    props: {
                        // The WP_Query var for the taxonomy
                        category: value.term_id,
                    }
                };
            });
            filters.all = {
                // Default label
                text:  'All categories',
                props: {
                    // The WP_Query var for the taxonomy
                    category: ''
                },
                priority: 10
            };
            this.filters = filters;
        }
    });
    /**
     * Extend and override wp.media.view.AttachmentsBrowser to include our new filter
     */
    var AttachmentsBrowser = wp.media.view.AttachmentsBrowser;
    wp.media.view.AttachmentsBrowser = wp.media.view.AttachmentsBrowser.extend({
        createToolbar: function() {
            // Make sure to load the original toolbar
            AttachmentsBrowser.prototype.createToolbar.call( this );
            this.toolbar.set( 'MediaLibraryCategoryFilter', new MediaLibraryCategoryFilter({
                controller: this.controller,
                model:      this.collection.props,
                priority: -75
            }).render() );
        }
    });
})()
```

what I am doing wrong? Any suggestion will be very helpful.

UPDATE: Screenshot of console from FireFox

[image]

Comment: First: Any errors output in your browser's developer console?  Are you sure the script is running cleanly / properly?

Comment: I am sorry for late reply! I don't if this is an error. Whatever I could see I added a screenshot of that.